# command 'gcc' not found in windows subsystem for linux

Tags: node.js, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to run some c files through wsl(ubuntu 20.04). I have set the path to the executable file in my windows env variable. It works good in cmd/powershell but as mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) we can access the windows env variables in wsl so I have tried running the command `gcc -v` in wsl but it says `Command 'gcc' not found` . Faced same issue with nodejs. `Command 'node' not found` but surprisingly when I type `node.exe` it worked!
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ55s.png)

Why is it so? How to resolve the issue with gcc? Do i need to install gcc compiler for WSL separately?

Comment: Ubuntu tells you exactly what to do in order to get `gcc` for Linux, and yes, you have to do that.

Comment: @Armali thanks for your answer but i have MinGw in my windows machine and set the path to bin file in env variable . As I type echo $PATH in ubuntu wsl it showed me the path but gcc commands were not running. Today I installed flex in ubuntu & along with that an updated version of gcc is installed . It is different from what version I have in windows.

Answer (score 1):

try download binaries of gcc.exe and put it in a folder and add it in your PATH.
Then you should be able to run gcc.exe in your WSL.

for me, was using MinGw and put all the binary for my sub system in /bin directory (added it to path, work perfectly)

Comment: thanks for your response, sir. Will try it.